# Angular 11 Nested Named Router outlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the follwing router:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent, outlet: 'c', children: [
          { path: 'clientinfo', component: ClientInfoComponent, outlet: 'i', children: [
              { path: 'cafe', component: ClientCafeComponent},
              { path: 'membership', component: ClientMembershipComponent },
              { path: 'pt', component: ClientPtComponent }
            ] }
        ] },
      { path: 'coach', component: CoachComponent, outlet: 'c'}] },
,
];
```

how can I load ClientInfoComponent from ClientComponent and ClientMembershipComponent from ClientInfoComponent using [routerLink] = '.....' ?

I have tried something like:

```
[routerLink]="['/main/(c:client)/(i:clientinfo/)']"
```

but no luck

thanks in advance

Comment: `/main/client/clientinfo/{cafe | membership | pt}`

Comment: they are Nested Named Router outlets

Comment: Then what is the issue here I'm not able to understand

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Ohkay... So why does `[routerLink]=" '/main/client/clientinfo/' "` isn't working for you?

Comment: You need to add an empty child to point it to `ClientInfoComponent` then the above url will point to that same component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a sulotion to my question and would like to share it. I rewrote my routes as follows:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], outlet: 'c' },
      { path: 'client/clientinfo', component: ClientInfoComponent, outlet: 'c', children: [
          { path: 'cafe', component: ClientCafeComponent},
          { path: 'membership', component: ClientMembershipComponent },
          { path: 'pt', component: ClientPtComponent }
        ] },
      { path: 'coach', component: CoachComponent, outlet: 'c'}] },
];
```

and in ClientComponent:

```
[routerLink]="['/main', { outlets: { c: ['client', 'clientinfo']}}]"
```

Hope that helps someone out there.